# Mounting a remote Windows drive on a local Windows machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking

I have access through Remote Desktop Connection to a Windows 7 machine. I believe that **Remote Desktop** allows me to mount the local drive on the remote machine, but I would like to do the **opposite**: mount a remote Windows 7 drive on my local Windows machine (running XP in my specific case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using remote desktop to connect to the Win7 machine I am assuming you are on the same network as that machine? If so just set the remote C: drive up as a share, give permission to "Everyone" or a specific user account that you have on the remote machine, and then map the drive on your local machine using "Map a network drive" with the remote machine's ip address and the share name that you setup. Let me know if this works or you need further detail. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Dan, do you mean if we are on the same subnet? We are not, but I can connect remotely using Remote Desktop via the machine's public IP address on the Internet. However, I can't mount the remote drives by mapping the network drive (it never connects). Do I need to set up additional permissions on the remote machine? Thanks!

Comment: If you are able to connect through remote desktop, you should be able to map a drive using the public IP address. You will need to set the drive up as a shared drive on the remote Win7 machine though, otherwise it will not let you map it. Here is a video on how to set the C drive up as a share http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW4jor40Pw0 Once you have the share you will map it on your local machine using the IP and the share name you entered for example \\10.1.1.1\sharename.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, that works for local drives on the remote machine, which is great! Do you know if I can share a *mapped drive* on the remote machine?

Comment: Does it display an IP address for the mapped drive on the remote mmachine? If so you should be able to map it the same way. If not, as a work around you could try creating a shortcut of the mapped drive. It will probably create it on the desktop by default, then move that shortcut to the C drive of the Remote machine which you now have mapped on your local machine. Then simply open the mapped C drive from your local machine and then double click the shortcut. I've never actually tried this, but it should work in theory. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you cannot so what you want to do using Remote Desktop.

The best way to do that would be to set up a VPN, and then you could map the remote drives.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more on this answer? I'm eager to try to this.